# Transforming a vector into another vector slowly

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors, 1 is the current direction of a moving object and the other is the new direction that I want that object to change to.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the current direction to gradually change to the new direction but I'm not really sure how to do this. It would be similar a ship slowly turning I guess.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Calculate the angle $\alpha$ between both vectors; then use a rotation matrix to incrementally change the direction of vector $v_1$ to that of $v_2$. For example start with a rotation of $\alpha/n$ for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then do another rotation again by $\alpha/n$. After $n$ rotations you get a full rotation of $n\alpha/n = \alpha$. This way you can discretize the rotation. For $n$ sufficiently large it gets smoother and smoother.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm checking out both methods but I think I'm starting to lean towards this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Velocity$(t) = tv_2  +(1-t)v_1$? Then the velocity starts at $v_1$ when $t=0$ and finishes at $v_2$ when $t=1$. If you want the change to be more gradual rescale to Velocity$(t) = (t/T)v_2  +(1-t/T)v_1$. That makes the change occur over $T$ units of time rather than $1$ unit.

Observe this method does not "rotate the vectors" onto one anther. For example if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are antiparallel this results in slowing down, stopping, then going the opposite way.

If you instead want to rotate you can use Velocity$(t) = \cos(t\pi/2)v_1  +\sin(t\pi/2)v_2$. The change takes place over one unit of time.

Comment: The last formula does not give a true rotation if $|v_1|\neq|v_2|$.

Comment: Of course you are right -- depending on what you mean by "true" and "rotation".